# How to detect the printed status or canceled status in web browser using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am just detecting the printed status in web browser.
As you can see , browser support the status as cancel or print button.
For seeing if user clicked cancel, print button, I am just using javascript.
but I had not got good result for that.
Are there good way to detect the status ?

Answer (score 2):

`window.print()` doesn't return any value.

I don't think there's a way to know if the user clicked *Save* or *Cancel*. It's more of your operating system's job to watch what's going on in there. There're, however, two event handlers

- `window.onbeforeprint` and
- `window.onafterprint`.

Code Snippet

```
window.onbeforeprint = function() {
    console.log('This will be called before the user prints.');
};

window.onafterprint = function() {
    console.log('This will be called after the user prints');   
};
```

Take a look [here](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks  for your reply,But window.onafterprint function has been ran in two condition whether user click cancel or print button.so I think with this function we can not detect correct action if print button clicked .So I had used already  this codes , but I had not luck

Comment: Check This once.
window.matchMedia("print").addListener(function() {
    alert("Print Dialog open.")
});

Comment: Thanks ,Ramu Bhusal .But there is no result for me .