# Detect Print button pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying to detect when the user press the button "Print" on the browser Print Window.

I already know the existence of "afterprint" event but it is fired also when the user press "Cancel", I need to call a function only when the print happens and not when the request is canceled.
I open the Print Window from javascript if this can help.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, the javascript events tied to the print preview window do not provide the print status as you have discovered. AFAIK there is no work around because it would be a security flaw if we were able to interact with the print preview window.

sorry :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect the printed status or canceled status in web browser using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46763153/how-to-detect-the-printed-status-or-canceled-status-in-web-browser-using-javascr)